# How to change button text in Ext js

Tags: extjs6

I am new to this Ext js. I am just working on buttons. I created one button which acted as toggle like on/off.In my case it is hide and show.I just shared my code below you can refer.In my code I have just created and hide one circle element initially.I have a button named Make Circle.When i click on the button it show show that hidden circle element also it has to change it text from Make circle into Hide circle which makes some sense.So I can click the same button to hide the circle element..Here the functionality works perfectly but the text on the button does not change.Please let me know why and how to solve it.

```
var makeCircleBtn = Ext.create({
    xtype : 'button',
    text : 'Make circle',
    renderTo : Ext.getBody(),

    var circle = Ext.create({**strong text**
                        xtype : 'draw',
                        id : 'circleId',
                        hidden:true,
                        sprites : [ {
                            type : 'circle',
                            fillStyle : 'red',
                            r : 50,
                            cx : 100,
                            cy : 100
                        } ],
                        height : 200,
                        width : 200,
                        renderTo : Ext.getBody(),

                    })// circle Ends Here

makeCircleBtn.on('click',function(){
    if (makeCircleBtn.text == 'Make circle') {
        makeCircleBtn.text = 'Hide Circle';
        Ext.getCmp('circleId').show();

    }else{
        makeCircleBtn.text = 'Make circle';
        Ext.getCmp('circleId').hide();
    }

})
```

Thank you 
Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I used ExtJs Classic toolkit version 6.0.1 to test this!

You can just change:

```
    makeCircleBtn.text = 'Hide Circle';
```

To this:

```
    makeCircleBtn.setText('Hide Circle');
```

That solved the problem for me.

But I also have some more suggestions.

1. Don't used the config `id`. There is a better way to give your components a unique id > `itemId`. `id` is global and will cause errors if you have multiple components with the same `id`. With `itemId` you don't run into this problem.
2. Instead of:

   ```
   if (makeCircleBtn.text == 'Make circle') {
      Ext.getCmp('circleId').show();

   } else{
      Ext.getCmp('circleId').hide();
   }
   ```

You could just do something like this:

```
yourCircleComponent.setVisible(yourCircleComponent.hidden);
```

That's a more elegant way to show/hide your circle component.

I also created a sencha fiddle for you to test it.
I also included the changes I suggested.

Here is the example:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/31mn

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much sir....It's working well . Thanks for that..I have some doubts

Comment: .I want to learn and want to become expert like you.Can you please suggest how to sharpen ourselfs to become good at Ext js like you.Thank you soooo much for time and effort .You have wrapped your code under Ext.application may i know why...And thank you sir

Comment: If you are new to stackoverflow: You can flag this an accept this answer as helpful so that other see that this case has been solved.

For the last part: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor > Sencha fiddle is just an online tool to test & share working ExtJs-Code (Similar to jsfiddle).
That's just the easiert way to render components to the screen to demonstrate bugs or showcase functionalities. If you have an account you can also save those examples like I did and share them (This could also help you to showcase your problems here)

Comment: For the learning part: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/guides/getting_started/getting_started.html 
You should definitly read all the guides that they offer. This should really help you. Other than that there are not many other things that I can offer you right now.

If you are working for a company and you are all new to ExtJs then maybe you should get a Training (https://www.sencha.com/training/#ext-js).

And at last: Always try to use the documentation. For most things you need you should find the proper functionality.